# Get Data Attribute of First Child Element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid, getattribute

I'm trying to get the data attributes of the first and last li in a ul. Something along the lines of...

```
var theTimeline = document.getElementById("the_timeline");
var timeline_items = $(theTimeline).filter('li');
var first_date = timline_items.lastChild.getAttribute("data-pubdate");
var last_date = timline_items.lastChild.getAttribute("data-pubdate");
```

Would any one be kind enough to give me a shove int the right direction?

Comment: this is `javascript` not `jQuery`

Comment: why are you using filter over a single element..?

Comment: `$("#the_timeline li:first").data("pubdate")` & `$("#the_timeline li:last").data("pubdate")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

```
$("#the_timeline li").first().data("pubdate");
```

last:

```
$("#the_timeline li:last").data("pubdate");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged it as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you can do:

```
$('#the_timeline > li').first().data("pubdate");
```

And:

```
$('#the_timeline > li:last').data("pubdate");
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, tagged .data("pubdate"); onto brunozrk's answer and it's cracked. Nice one.

Comment: Welcome :) Glad to have helped